# custom data validation in Excel for alpha-numeric-alpha value

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, alphanumeric

I want to force users to enter data in a specific cell in a sequence like **ABCDE1234F**

i.e. first five characters must me letters then  four digits and last must be a letter using **custom data validation**.

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: Can VBA be used to write a function to validate the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite long:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH("~"&MID(A1,ROW($1:$5),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))),ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH("~"&MID(A1,ROW($6:$9),1),"0123456789"))),ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH("~"&MID(A1,10,1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))),LEN(A1)=10)
```

It goes through each of the required text characters and checks if it is a number or a string.  Then it test the full range of numbers for text.  It also ensures that it is ten characters long.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear and with your help I could find where I made mistake.

Comment: @AbhinnWasav please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as being answered.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sir it also allows special characters. Is there any possibility to allow alphanumeric value only?

Comment: @AbhinnWasav see edit.  It got a whole lot longer.  It will now only allow A-Z and 0-9.

Comment: I can't paste that formula into data validation for Excel 2010

Comment: @AbhinnWasav as CoveGeek just pointed out the formula is too long for data validation.

Comment: @AbhinnWasav I finally found a shorter formula that will work as direct data validation formula.  See edit.

Comment: @CoveGeek I was able to get a formula to fit in the data validation.  Try the edit.

Comment: @AbhinnWasav did the new formula work?   If so please mark as correct. It is something only you can do. It will close the question as being answered. Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following formula

```
=AND(ISTEXT(LEFT(A1,5)),ISNUMBER(MID(A1,6,4)*1),ISTEXT(MID(A1,10,1)),IF(LEN(A1)=10,TRUE,FALSE))
```