# EXCEL Multiple data validation with unique ID

Tags: excel

I want to force users to enter data in a specific cell in a sequence like ABCDE1234F

And I found the answer (provided Link), but one more condition for me is it should be used as unique ID.

Link:
[custom data validation in Excel for alpha-numeric-alpha value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243555/custom-data-validation-in-excel-for-alpha-numeric-alpha-value?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Add another check within the AND function to make sure the value is unique within the desired range. For example, to ensure A1 is unique within A1:A10:

```
COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,A1)=1
```